# Command to extract value between two variables and store it in a variable

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to extract the value(number) between two variables and store the value in another variable.

I am using sed command, but I am not getting any output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
variable1=`cat $1`
variable2=`echo "$variable1" | cut -c 18`
echo "$variable2"
variable3=`echo "$variable1" | cut -c 60`
echo "$variable3"
string="${variable3}xyz${variable2}"
echo $string
line=`sed -n '/'"$string"'/,/'"$variable2"'/ p' $1`
echo $line
```

Please suggest me a way to extract number between  $searchString and  $variable2, lets say between **$string** which is : **&xyz!** and **$variable2** which is : **!** , I have 60 ie **&xyz!60!**
So I need to extract 60.

I also tried with

```
line=`sed -nr "s/$string([0-9]+),$variable2/\1/ p" $1`
```

but when I echoed $line it printed the entire file content

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a complete example with the contents of the file. It's hard to figure out what this is about in fact.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done just with shell parameter substutition:

```
# setup
line='hello&xyz!60!world'
string='&xyz!'
variable2='!'

# now, remove from the beginning up to the first instance of "&xyz!"
tmp=${line#*$string}

# $tmp now holds 60!world

# remove from the end the last "!" and all following characters
result=${tmp%$variable2*}
echo $result
# => 60
```

---

It looks like your sed command is failing due to the comma

1. no comma in input, so nothing matches, thus nothing printed

   ```
   $ set -x
   $ echo "$line" | sed -nr "s/$string([0-9]+),$variable2/\1/ p"
   + sed -nr 's/&xyz!([0-9]+),!/\1/ p'
   + echo 'hello&xyz!60!world'
   ```
2. remove the comma, now we have a match, but the prefix and suffix remain

   ```
   $ echo "$line" | sed -nr "s/$string([0-9]+)$variable2/\1/ p"
   + sed -nr 's/&xyz!([0-9]+)!/\1/ p'
   + echo 'hello&xyz!60!world'
   hello60world
   ```
3. also match pre and post text

   ```
   $ echo "$line" | sed -nr "s/.*$string([0-9]+)$variable2.*/\1/ p"
   + sed -nr 's/.*&xyz!([0-9]+)!.*/\1/ p'
   + echo 'hello&xyz!60!world'
   60
   ```